# Mathematica won't simplify the expression with obvious common factor of a fraction

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have an expression obtain from an integral, which is:

```
Integrate[ϵ^2/Sqrt[(ϵ - u)^2 + Δ^2], ϵ] // FullSimplify
```

The denominator and numerator of the result have an obvious common factor:

```
Sqrt[Δ^2 + (u - ϵ)^2]
```

How can I let mathematica to cancel this common factor? I have tried `Cancel` and `Refine` all
the variables to be positive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Integrate[ϵ^2/Sqrt[(ϵ - u)^2 + Δ^2], ϵ] // Apart // FullSimplify
```

Answer (score 3):

You could help *Mathematica* by temporarily renaming the factor.

```
exp = Integrate[ϵ^2/Sqrt[(ϵ - u)^2 + Δ^2], ϵ] // FullSimplify
exp /. (Δ^2 + (u - ϵ)^2) :> w
FullSimplify[%] /. w :> Δ^2 + (u - ϵ)^2
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]